# Disable a Tab in JSP

Tags: jsp

Is there anyway to disable a tab in JSP which is created using bootstrap? I mean I don't want to disable using JavaScript or Jquery. I want to make a tab disabled when I create the page itself and later I will enable.
This is my code to create tab:

```
<div class="navbar btn-navbar">
            <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#datacollector" target="main"
                        data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                    <li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType"><a
                        href="#fromDatabase" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Database</a></li>
                    <li id="fromFile" class="selectDataloadType"><a
                        href="#fromFiles" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            File</a></li>
                    <li id="email" class="selectDataloadType"><a
                        href="#fromEmail" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Email</a></li>
                    <li id="webServices" class="selectDataloadType"><a href="#fromWebServices"
                        target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#datamap" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                            Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Suppose I want to disable the second tab(**LI** with id *fromDB*), is there anyway to specify it as disabled? like

```
<li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType disabled"><a.......</a></li>
```

or

```
<li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType" style="disabled"><a.......</a></li>
```

Both are not working. But similar to that is there anyway? I don't want to use any script for this otherwise I knw on window load I can disable it. But I want to specify it here... So is there anyway?

Comment: what you exactly need? Do you wan to disable hyperlink initially ?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly I want.

Comment: Are you getting data from database and want to show on jsp ?

Comment: yes. That is later thing. Using JSTL I am able to change the disable or enable part once I get how to set it first

Comment: I have posted the answer.Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any status when your hyperlink will be disable ? When you are displaying fetched data from database , you should get a status for disable the hyperlink. And check that status as below :-

Example :-

```
<%
//Set this status in servlet/action servlet
String  sts=(String)session.getAttributes("tabsts");


%>
```

Use in JSP

```
<li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType">
    <a <%if(sts!=null && sts.equals("yes")){) %> href="Your link"  <%}%> > 
        Your Data from Data Base 
    </a>

</li>
```

If your href tag is not written on  tag, then it is disable in nature.